# Bind the closing of a first modal to the opening of a second modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

So when the first modal (this.$avatarModal) is closed, I would like a second modal (this.$modaldata) to open.:

The following sequence works however there are issues with the scrolling of the second modal not functioning:

```
    this.$avatarModal.modal('hide');
    this.$modaldata.modal('show');
```

As a solution to the scrolling issue, the dev on [github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/15489) are recommending to bind the event. However the following code, using .on does not work (the second modal does not open.

```
    this.$avatarModal.modal('hide');
    this.$avatarModal.on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
      this.$modaldata.modal('show');
});
```

However, If i replace the show event with an alert, the alert opens:

```
    this.$avatarModal.modal("hide");
    this.$avatarModal.on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
      window.alert('hidden event fired!');
});
```

This tells me that all the commands here are working, however having the 'show' method within the .on('hidden'... event does not seem to work.

Is there a reason for this incompatibility and how I can correctly open up the second modal after the first modal closes?

Comment: Your code looks generally correct. What does `this` evaluate to?

Comment: @isherwood this.$container = $element within a function. this.init(); all elements appear in scope since they all will function, just not when you combine the hidden event and show method

Comment: @Rhillz I don't understand your reply. But isherwood makes an excellent point: `this` has a different value inside the function call. If I'm not mistaken, `this` inside the function should be the same as `this.$avatarModal` outside it. So the console should say it's failed because `this.$modaldata` is undefined and therefore has no `modal` method. To rectify this, write `var $modaldata = this.$modaldata;` before setting the handler, then replace `this.$modaldata` with `$modaldata`.

Comment: @DavidKnipe this not only solved this glitch but others on my page as well. Good stuff thank you both. if you want to put as an answer i'll check it