# Can't capture Bootstrap 3.3.6 on close modal event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to trigger another event on modal close event, here's what I've tried.

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
    alert("modal is closed");
});
```

but unfortunately, it does not work like 'nothing happen'. Any help, clues, ideas, suggestions, recommendations please?

**UPDATE**

Here's my HTML markup

```
<button class="btn thehide" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#notification_dialog" id="notification_trigger_button">Open dialog</button>
    <div id="notification_dialog" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content" id="text">
            <div class="modal-header padding_zero">
              <!-- <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button> -->
              <h4 class="modal-title display_table full_width text_transform_uppercase">Dialog</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            </div>
            <div class="extend cler j_line"></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button class="btn btn-default margin_zero" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The docs say this: `$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  // do something…
})`

Comment: Please provide HTML markup too.

Comment: @Abhi: that would be okay, as long as im binding it to the right selector, I have also tried what the docs instruct but still not working.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `debugger;` in the script and see what is happening.

Comment: @Abhi: there's no errors showing or such as on the console and also, I stated above, that it does not actually work.

Comment: You might wanna try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27807225/bind-the-closing-of-a-first-modal-to-the-opening-of-a-second-modal?rq=1

The OP has said that if they use `window.alert()` it works.Ikr. But worth a try.

Comment: I have found out that it has a conflict on the datatable 1.10.11 because If I remove the datatables scripts and initialization, the 'hidden.bs.modal' works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check maybe that http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/1370/

If I anderstand well, is what you want.

```
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  alert("Hello");
})
```

Comment: Is jquery included twice ? I can be the cause. I get that once.

Comment: I'm sure Jquery included only once.

Comment: I have found out that it has a conflict on the datatable 1.10.11 because If I remove the datatables scripts and initialization, the 'hidden.bs.modal' works.

Comment: Ok, I see :) Exact same issue than me. It's probably because jQuery is incuded inside the datatables je, try to take the library without jquery and test again.

Comment: Thanks! I just check the datatables and It did include the Jquery with it, after I reset my download set up without the Jquery included for the datatables, everything works now.